# Can I change the font style of a labelText in a TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the font of the labelText with a Google Font. I already imported the package for Google Fonts. Here is the code below:

```
TextFormField(
                labelText: 'Label Text',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  letterSpacing: 1.3,
                  fontFamily: GoogleFonts.openSans().fontFamily,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Is there a way to change the font of the labelText?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way**

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Hello',
            labelStyle: GoogleFonts.aboreto(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.amber
              )
            )
          ),
        )
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your response! but it's a textFormField() in which i can't add or change the font.

Comment: Answer edited, please check again

Comment: it's still not working, i've watched a flutter google font dependency video and it says that it can only be applied to Text() and ThemeData()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, like with a normal `TextStyle`:

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: ' text',
      labelStyle: TextStyle( 
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: i want to change the font style of the text inside the TextFormField()